# Get a gridview Column Heading after editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm working with an ASP.net project and have a gridview that has a dataset from an sql database as a datasource.

When I change the values in the gridview, I would like to update the dataset so that I can use that dataset to update the database again.

The statement that I have so far.

This is the part I'm having trouble with. I can get the selected row, but not the selected column name to update the dataset with.

```
 myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[e.RowIndex][?] = "";
```

Full code on the RowUpdating event.

```
protected void grdViewDetails_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
               //Just get the dataset populated from my database (sql)
                DataSet dsOriginal = dbConn.returnSqlDataset(query);

                //update the dataset here so that you can update the database again.
                foreach (TableCell cell in grdViewDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
                {
                    //set the employeeid so you can update the dataset
                    if (cell.Controls[0] is TextBox)
                    {
                        TextBox textbox = (TextBox)cell.Controls[0];
                        string value = textbox.Text; //This is just a tester to see if the value is correct
                     //   dsOriginal.Tables[0].Rows[e.RowIndex][?] = value; //Here is the problem, how to get the selected column name

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (cell.Controls[0] is CheckBox)
                        {
                            CheckBox chkBoxWeek = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];
                            Boolean checkStatus = chkBoxWeek.Checked;  //This is just a tester to see if the value is correct
                          //dsOriginal.Tables[0].Rows[e.RowIndex][?] = checkStatus; //Here is the problem, how to get the selected column name
                        }
                    }
                }

                //Use the updated dataset to update the database with.
                dbConn.udpatCourse(dsOriginal );


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the [`GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx) collection to find out what has been updated.

This slightly adapted from the linked MSDN documentation:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in e.NewValues)
{
    string columName = entry.Key;
    string userInput = e.NewValues[entry.Key];
    // Now you can do stuff with this info that meets your logic needs
}
```

If I'm reading your question correctly, you should be able to get what you need from here.